# Multiple type parameters on a scala method

Tags: scala, generics, methods

In Java, a `Map` could be parameterized as `Map<K, V>`, but in Scala, I don't know what's the meaning of multiple type parameters on a method, for example:

```
def foo[T, U, R]
```

It is easy to understand when a method parameterized by one type parameter. such as `def f[T](t: T)` .

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: If you don't mind a shameless plug, I wrote a [series of blog posts](http://proseand.co.nz/2014/02/17/type-programming-shifting-from-values-to-types/) aimed at grappling with the basics of type-level programming in Scala.  I likewise come from a Java background, so I believe it will help you.

Comment: @joescii: That's a great blog post, but I don't think this question is really about "type-level programming" by the usual definition—it's just plain old generics, and is more-or-less equivalent to the Java version.

Comment: @TravisBrown: I agree with your point, and your answer below. My thought is that a more general understanding for this user would come from exposure to type-level programming.

Answer (score 11):

Suppose I want to write a generic method that operates on any old `Map[K, V]`—I'd have to include both type parameters in the method type parameter list:

```
def mapToList[K, V](m: Map[K, V]): List[(K, V)] = m.toList
```

Three parameters works the same way. Suppose I have a function `A => B` and another `B => C`, and I want to compose them to get a function from `A` to `C`—I need all three types in my parameter list:

```
def andThen[A, B, C](f: A => B, g: B => C): A => C = (a: A) => g(f(a))
```

Both of these examples are trivial, since we already have `m.toList` and `f andThen g`, but they should make the use case for multiple type parameters clear.